# Custom Converter set by Dozer java API not invoked for field

Tags: dozer

I am using the [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) framework to convert between Java Beans. I would like to create my mapping using the Java Api of Dozer instead of XML in order to be able to manipulate and configure my custom converters.

If I run my converter using Alternative 1 in the code below with alt 2 removed - mapping in xml file, the conversion works fine and my custom converters are invoked.
If I run my converter using Alternative 2 - mapping using java API, the mapper never invokes my Converter. The bean is converted, but the nested field of the same type is being ignored, in the code below, the parent field is null after conversion.

```
Organization org = ...init organization....
OrganizationDto orgDto = new MyConverter().convert(organization, OrganizationDto.class);
assertEquals(3,orgDto.getParent().getX()) //Fails due to NPE since parent field is not copied
```

I know that class level custom converters are not supported through the java API, but field level converters looks like they is supported since it is provided in the java mapping API [example](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/apimappings.html).

(I am also aware that Dozer authors recommend using Dozer as a singleton, but thats not included in sample below.)

Any hints?

```
public class OrganizationDto {
   int x;
   OrganizationDto parent ;
   // getters and setters....
}

public class Organization {
   int x;
   Organization parent ;
   // getters and setters....
}


public class MyConverter{


private DozerBeanMapper mapper = null;

public MyConverter() {
        mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        // Alternative 1 - works 
//          List<String> myMappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
//          myMappingFiles.add("myBeanMappings.xml");
//          mapper.setMappingFiles(myMappingFiles);

        // Alternative 2 - does not work
        Map<String,CustomConverter> customConvertersWithId = new HashMap<String, CustomConverter>();
        customConvertersWithId.put("OrganizationDetailsConverter", new OrganizationDetailsConverter());
        mapper.setCustomConvertersWithId(customConvertersWithId);

        // Also tried variants using
        //mapper.setCustomConverters(Collections.<CustomConverter> singletonList(new OrganizationDetailsConverter()));

        BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
            protected void configure() {
                mapping(OrganizationDto.class, Organization.class)
                .fields("parent",
                        "parent",
                        customConverterId("OrganizationDetailsConverter"));
                }
            };          
            mapper.addMapping(builder);
    }

    public <T, S> T convert(S fromBean, Class<T> toBeanClass) {
    return mapper.map(fromBean, toBeanClass);
    }

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
      http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
    <mapping>
        <class-a>foo.OrganizationDto</class-a>
        <class-b>foo.Organization</class-b>
        <field custom-converter="foo.OrganizationDetailsConverter">
            <a>parent</a>
            <b>parent</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DozerMap {

   public static class ContainerA {
      private A a;
      public A getA() { return a; }
      public void setA(A a) { this.a = a; }
   }

   public static class ContainerB {
      private B b;
      public B getB() { return b; }
      public void setB(B b) { this.b = b; }
   }

   private static class A { };

   private static class B { };

   static class ConverterImpl extends DozerConverter<A, B> {

      ConverterImpl() {
         super(A.class, B.class);
      }

      @Override
      public B convertTo(A source, B destination) {
         Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Invoked");
         return destination;
      }

      @Override
      public A convertFrom(B source, A destination) {
         Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Invoked");
         return destination;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
      mapper.setCustomConverters(Collections.<CustomConverter> singletonList(new ConverterImpl()));
      BeanMappingBuilder foo = new BeanMappingBuilder() {

         @Override
         protected void configure() {
            mapping(ContainerA.class, ContainerB.class).fields("a", "b", FieldsMappingOptions.customConverter(ConverterImpl.class));
         }
      };
      mapper.setMappings(Collections.singletonList(foo));
      ContainerA containerA = new ContainerA();
      containerA.a = new A();
      ContainerB containerB = mapper.map(containerA, ContainerB.class);
   }
}
```